# Interface Eth1 not visible in Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, ethernet, network-interface

I am new to linux networking. Basically I wanted to use eth1 interface of my PC in VirtualBox but I simply don't find the eth1 interface. Below are the ifconfig and sudo ifconfig eth1 outputs. Please help me with valuable ideas.

Thanks.

o/p from Host :

```
sameer@sameer-Vostro-1015:~$ ifconfig
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ac:6f:6b:18:62  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:2338 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2338 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:314892 (314.8 KB)  TX bytes:314892 (314.8 KB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:7c:8f:07:a6:58  
      inet6 addr: fe80::227c:8fff:fe07:a658/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:23408 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:17505 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:15494141 (15.4 MB)  TX bytes:2203889 (2.2 MB) 


sameer@sameer-Vostro-1015:~$ sudo ifconfig eth1
eth1: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

o/p from Virtual Box :

[O/P from VirtualBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gB9f.png)

Comment: 1) Do you run this `ifconfig` in your host system? or in a guest system under VirtualBox? I guess it's the former. If so: 2) do you have at least two physical network ports in your PC?

Comment: I'm going to assume that the output is from the VM. That eth0 is not the eth0 on your host - It's a virtual network adapter. Look in VBox's config.

Comment: If the VM only has one interface, then it will be known as eth0, regardless of what it is known as on the host system.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski that was the O/P from my host. But even in the O/P from VirtualBox the Eth1 wasn't visible. I have edited my question with the image from VirtualBox. Kindly check

Comment: @VirtualDXS that was the O/P from my host

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I have one ethernet port and one modem port.

Comment: Are you sure your host even has an eth1?

Comment: @VirtualDXS Any way to know that considering most of the PCs have a eth1?

Comment: Most PCs do NOT have an eth1. Most PCs only have eth0.

Comment: Some PCs have a second network adapter, which will be eth1. How many physical ethernet ports do you have?

Comment: @VirtualDXS Okay i get it now. I just have 1 Eth port. But my virtualBox should have two ports right? One should be a NAT interface that it can use to access the Internet, and the other should be a host-only interface to enable it to communicate with the host machine

Comment: The same interface is used for both.

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could create a Eth1 interface on my Virtual Box. I had to do two things:

1. Strangely the preference option is not visible on VirtualBox for ubuntu. So I had to press ctrl + G to get into it. Then I went to the network tab and created a hostonly adapter by clicking on a small button at top right corner among the three icons given.
2. Then I had to enable the interface by running the command

sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.56.101 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

Then it was done :)

[Eth1 interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CvNB.png)

Answer (score 0):

The guest VM does not have direct access to the network interfaces of your host PC, it has a virtual network adapter. If you want all traffic from your VM to use a specific interface, you need to enter the VirtualBox network settings for that VM and configure Bridged Mode with the interface in question. The default mode is NAT, where VirtualBox will essentially act as a router for your virtual machines and the network complexity is hidden to the guests; in bridged mode, the VM is essentially allowed to use the interface directly, and from a network perspective it is as if a second interface is connected to the port. See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html, specifically section 6.5, "Bridged Networking".

Bear in mind that you can add multiple network adapters in the VirtualBox config, so if you want multiple interfaces on your host to be available to your VM in this way, you'd just set up multiple bridged interfaces, each bound to a different interface on the host.

Answer (score 0):

There is no eth1 on your host - eth0 is the only network card you have.

Comment: I finally could create a Eth1. We need to configure it and give static Ip address to it. Below is the command : 
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.56.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up